# Background-size contain logo image only when width size start touching logo

Tags: html, css, background, contain, background-size

When adjusting the width size of the page i only want the logo starts containing when there is no room left on either sides of the logo so at that point adjust to the width of the page. Must be quite easy! In the fiddle example is seems to act like i want, but doesn't with my own code it contains the background size (logo) al the time.

I want the logo center page with a one size and adjust the size when the page width reaches the both ends of the logo. Hope you understand my English.

Here the: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/621zq14q/1/)

```
#logo {
display: block;
background: url("http://cdn4.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-color: white;
background-size: contain;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-o-background-size: contain;
height: 30%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
-index: -100;
```

}

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yes that whats confusing me it works in the fiddle code but not on my end with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code by creating a single html file with the css in style tags, it didn't work with IE but worked with Chrome and FF.!